# MIPS: program that takes in user input values and calculates exponents using loops

Tags: assembly, mips, mips32, mars-simulator

So I have this whole program written out and my loops for calculating the exponents work in a program of their own but when i step through the program they are not running through multiple times the way that i want them to and the out put the program is giving is all 0s.

Here is the code:
EDIT: Ive updated the code to what I have currently plus a division function in the end.  Currently im getting the proper values for the first 3 loops sets. This means that i am getting the right value for f, but the second component of g which is d^w is not spitting out the right values.

```
 ##designed and written by Aidan Rosser-Jones
.data #data needed
    A : .word 0
    B : .word 0
    C : .word 0
    D : .word 0 ## A-D are the base values that the user inputs
    x : .word 8
    y : .word 5
    z : .word 7
    w : .word 5 ## x-w are the exponents with hardcoded student ID numbers

    userPrompt : .asciiz "Please enter four integers seperated by an enter key." ## prompting the user
    F          : .asciiz "f(decimal) : " ## result for F in base 10
    binaryF    : .asciiz "f(binary)  : " ## result for F in base 2
    G          : .asciiz "g(decimal) : " ## result for G in base 10
    binaryG    : .asciiz "g(binary)  : " ## result for G in base 2
    quotientH  : .asciiz "h quotient : " ## quotient result for H
    remainderH : .asciiz "h remainder : " # remainder result for H
    skipLine   : .asciiz "\n"            ## for printing a new line
    
.text ##switching back to code section
    
    .globl main
        main:
            #first we must prompt the user for the four integers
            la $a0, userPrompt #loading the prompt from data section into $a0
            li $v0, 4          #syscall for printing a string
            syscall            # this actually does the printing
            
            #now we gotta read the first integer
            li $v0, 5
            syscall
            
            lw $s4, A          #loading the address of variable a into $t0
            move $s4, $v0      #copying the user input to $t0
            
            #time to read the second integer (basically second verse, same as the first for the next 3)
            li $v0, 5
            syscall
            
            lw $s5, B
            move $s5, $v0
            
            #3rd integer
            li $v0, 5
            syscall
            
            lw $s6, C
            move $s6, $v0
            
            #4th integer
            li $v0, 5
            syscall
            
            lw $s7, D
            move $s7, $v0
            
            #time to do some calculations
            #calculating a^x
            move $t1, $s4           #loading address of A into $t1
            ##lw $t1, ($t1)       #loading the value of A into $t1
            
            la $t2, x           #loading address of x into $t2
            lw $t2, ($t2)       #loading the value of x into $t2
            
            #loop prep
            move $t5, $t1       #answer = base
            move $t6, $t1       #increment = base
            li $t3, 1           # i = 1
            li $t4, 1           # j = 1
            
        For0:   
                ble $t2, $t3, Exit0 #for(i =1; i<x; i++)
                addi $t3, $t3, 1    #i++
                li $t4, 1           #resesting j to 1 so nested loop works properly
                move $t6, $t5
                j For1
                
        For1:  
                ble $t1, $t4, For0  #for(j=1; j < A; j++)
                add $t5, $t5, $t6   #answer+=increment              
                addi $t4, $t4, 1    #j++
                j For1
                
        Exit0:
                move $s0, $t5       #storing a^x in $s0
                
                #calculating b^y
            move $t1, $s5           #loading address of B into $t1
            ##lw $t1, ($t1)       #loading the value of B into $t1
            
            la $t2, y           #loading address of y into $t2
            lw $t2, ($t2)       #loading the value of y into $t2
            
            #loop prep
            move $t5, $t1       #answer = base
            move $t6, $t1       #increment = base
            li $t3, 1           # i = 1
            li $t4, 1           # j = 1
            
        For2:   
                ble $t2, $t3, Exit1 #for(i =1; i<y; i++)
                addi $t3, $t3, 1    #i++
                li $t4, 1           #resesting j to 1 so nested loop works properly
                move $t6, $t5
                j For3
                
        For3:  
                ble $t1, $t4, For2  #for(j=1; j < B; j++)
                add $t5, $t5, $t6   #answer+=increment
                addi $t4, $t4, 1    #j++
                j For3
                
        Exit1:
                move $s1, $t5       #storing b^y in $s0
                
                #calculating c^z
                move $t1, $s6           #loading address of C into $t1
            ##lw $t1, ($t1)       #loading the value of C into $t1
            
            la $t2, z           #loading address of z into $t2
            lw $t2, ($t2)       #loading the value of z into $t2
            
            #loop prep
            move $t5, $t1       #answer = base
            move $t6, $t1       #increment = base
            li $t3, 1           # i = 1
            li $t4, 1           # j = 1
            
        For4:   
                ble $t2, $t3, Exit2 #for(i =1; i<z; i++)
                addi $t3, $t3, 1    #i++
                li $t4, 1           #resesting j to 1 so nested loop works properly
                move $t6, $t5
                j For5
                
        For5:  
                ble $t1, $t4, For4  #for(j=1; j < c; j++)
                add $t5, $t5, $t6   #answer+=increment
                addi $t4, $t4, 1    #j++
                j For5
                
        Exit2:
                move $s2, $t5       #storing c^z in $s0
                
                #calculating d^w
                move $t1, $s6           #loading address of D into $t1
            ##lw $t1, ($t1)       #loading the value of D into $t1
            
            la $t2, w           #loading address of w into $t2
            lw $t2, ($t2)       #loading the value of w into $t2
            
            #loop prep
            move $t5, $t1       #answer = base
            move $t6, $t1       #increment = base
            li $t3, 1           # i = 1
            li $t4, 1           # j = 1
            
        For6:   
                ble $t2, $t3, Exit3 #for(i =1; i<w; i++)
                addi $t3, $t3, 1    #i++
                li $t4, 1           #resesting j to 1 so nested loop works properly
                move $t6, $t5
                j For7
                
        For7:  
                ble $t1, $t4, For6  #for(j=1; j < D; j++)
                add $t5, $t5, $t6   #answer+=increment
                addi $t4, $t4, 1    #j++
                j For7
                
        Exit3:
                move $s3, $t5       #storing d^w in $s3
                
                ##THIS IS FOR TESTING PURPOSES ONLY
                li $v0, 1
                move $a0, $s3
                syscall
                ##CONCLUDING TEST CODE
                
                #calculating and storing f = a^x + b^y
                add $s0, $s0, $s1   #f = $s0
                
                #calculating and storing g = c^z + d^w
                add $s2, $s2, $s3   #g = $s2
                
                #now lets print out all of the data, starting with a fresh line to avoid confusion!
                la $a0, skipLine
                li $v0, 4
                syscall             #skips a line
                
                #printing f
                la $a0, F
                li $v0, 4
                syscall
                
                li $v0, 1
                move $a0, $s0
                syscall             #print f in decimal 
                
                #printing new line for organization
                la $a0, skipLine
                li $v0, 4
                syscall             #skips a line
                
                la $a0, binaryF
                li $v0, 4
                syscall
                
                li $v0, 35
                move $a0, $s0
                syscall             #this should print the binary f
                
                #printing new line for organization
                la $a0, skipLine
                li $v0, 4
                syscall             #skips a line
                
                #lets print g!
                la $a0, G
                li $v0, 4
                syscall
                
                li $v0, 1
                move $a0, $s2
                syscall             #this should print decimal g
                
                #printing new line for organization
                la $a0, skipLine
                li $v0, 4
                syscall             #skips a line
                
                #lets print g but binary this time!
                la $a0, binaryG
                li $v0, 4
                syscall
                
                li $v0, 35
                move $a0, $s2
                syscall
                
                #now we must calculate h = f/g
                #division prep
                # f = $s0
                # g = $s2
                add $t0, $zero, $s0 #copies the value of f into $t0
                add $t1, $zero, $s1 #copies the value of g into $t1
                add $t2, $zero, $zero #make $t2 the counter starting at 0
          
    div_loop:
            sle $t3, $t2, $t1 #checks if equal
            beq $t3, $zero, end_divis
            sub $t0, $t0, $t1
            addi $t2, $t2, 1 
            j div_loop
    end_divis:
            move $s6, $t2 # stores quotient in $s6
            move $s7, $t0 # stores remainder in $s7
            
            #now its time to print the values for h
            #printing new line for organization
                la $a0, skipLine
                li $v0, 4
                syscall             #skips a line
                
                la $a0, quotientH
                li $v0, 4
                syscall       # prints quotientH string
                
                li $v0, 1
                move $a0, $s6
                syscall   #print integer value for quotient H
                
                #printing new line for organization
                la $a0, skipLine
                li $v0, 4
                syscall             #skips a line
                
                la $a0, remainderH
                li $v0, 4
                syscall    #print remainder H string
                
                li $v0, 1
                move $a0, $s7
                syscall   #print integer value for remainder H
                
                #terminate the program
                li $v0, 10
                syscall
```

If some of the comments are off I apologize.  I copy and pasted the loops and then changed where the calculations were stored and the loop names for jumping purposes to achieve the functionality needed.

Currently my output looks like this:

Please enter four integers seperated by an enter key.2
3
1
2
1 (THIS IS A TEST PRINT FOR THE VALUE OF d^w)
f(decimal) : 499
f(binary)  : 00000000000000000000000111110011
g(decimal) : 2
g(binary)  : 00000000000000000000000000000010
h quotient : 244
h remainder : -58793
-- program is finished running --

As previously stated the problem has something to do with my loops but I've been staring at it for awhile now and cannot figure out whats up.  Any help would be greatly appreciated as I have been learning MIPS for less than a week now.

And for reference the loops were modeled after this Java code I wrote:

```
/*
 * Written by Aidan Rosser-Jones
 */
public class exponentLoop {
    public static final int BASE = 5;
    public static final int POWER = 6;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int answer = BASE;
        int increment = BASE;
        for(int i = 1; i < POWER; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 1; j < BASE; j++)
            {
                answer += increment;
            }
            increment = answer;
        }
        System.out.println(answer);

    }

}
```

**For this project we arent allowed to use any sort of multiplication instruction or functions, thats why the code is formatted the way it is

Comment: Single step in the debugger, and see when/where something goes wrong.  As you single step, verify that each instruction produces the value you expect, and, that the flow of control is as you expect.  You'll see things that don't make sense, and those should be fixed.

Comment: okay so it seems that im not properly storing the user input

Comment: I do believe ive gotten it to work.  I'm going to do the math by hand to get the output im looking for and then run the program to see if im getting the same results.

Comment: So i am getting the proper results for the first 3 function, but the 4th set of loops that calculate d^w is not working function properly, its spitting out 1s and 0s depending on input